# How to fetch a sum from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
$views = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(`views`) FROM `Beats` WHERE `author_id` = '$uid' ");
$views1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($views);
$views2 = $views1['views_sum'];
```

But when I try to echo it, it is empty. I tried to make `$views2 = $views1["views_sum"];`, but it still doesn't work. When I check mysqli_query request at the database it works. So the problem is in fetching, but how do I fetch it properly?

```
$views2 = $views1['views'];
```

This doesn't work either.

Comment: Should be `SELECT SUM(\`views\`) as views_sum FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
} 
$sql = "SELECT SUM(`views`) FROM `Beats` WHERE `author_id` = '".$uid."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// Fetch all
print_r(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)); 

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [views] => 26 ) )
```